# Proving that this function is an Endomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Given that $\mathbb{C}G = W_1 \oplus W_2$ and $1 = e_1 + e_2$ where $e_1 \in W_1$ and $e_2 \in W_2$

Also Knowing that $$w_1e_1 = w_1, w_2e_1 = 0$$ $$w_1e_2 = 0 , w_2e_2 = w_2$$

Let $x \in G$

Now it is claimed that the function $$\phi:w \to we_1x^{-1} \space \space  (w \in \mathbb{C}G)$$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}G$.

That's to say that $\phi(wg) = \phi(w)g \space \space \forall g \in G$ and hence $$wge_1x^{-1} = we_1x^{-1}g$$

But how to prove that the above equality holds ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: What are $w_1$ and $w_2$? Arbitrary elements of $W_1$ and $W_2$, respectively?

Comment: yes @AlexanderDunlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}G$ as a vector space, not as a $\mathbb{C}G$-module. I'm guessing that this comes from a development of inner products of characters, where the trace of this endomorphism is calculated, which doesn't require it to be a $\mathbb{C}G$-module endomorphism.

Comment: So how can you verify it's an endomorphism of $\mathbb{CG}$ as a vector space. You are right by the way about the inner product thing !

Comment: @alkabary That's just saying that multiplying by $e_1x^{-1}$ is linear. But multiplying by any element of the group algebra is linear.